# Insertar un registro en dos tablas relacionadas

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un proyecto donde quiero insertar un registro en dos tablas, donde la tabla **usuario** tiene una *llave primaria*, y tengo una tabla **cliente** donde hay una *llave foránea* relacionada a la *llave primaria* de la primera.

Lo que he tratado de hacer es usar dos **try catch**, uno para crear el registros para la tabla **usuario**, recuperar el id del ultimo registro del mismo, e insertar el registro de la tabla **cliente** con el dato del último registro de **usuario**. El problema es que cuando ejecuto mi código ce el segundo registro en la segunda tabla. Como puedo hacerlos: A continuación muestro el código php.

```
try {
   if ($conSQL) {
                $conSQL->beginTransaction();

                $sqlStatment = $conSQL->prepare(

                    "INSERT INTO usuario VALUES(
                    default,
                    :usuario,
                    :tipo,
                    :nombre,
                    :app,
                    :apm,
                    :contrasena)");

                $sqlStatment->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario);
                $sqlStatment->bindParam(':tipo', $tipo);
                $sqlStatment->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre);
                $sqlStatment->bindParam(':app', $app);
                $sqlStatment->bindParam(':apm', $apm);
                $sqlStatment->bindParam(':contrasena', $contrasena);

                //linea agregada
                $sqlStatment->execute();

                $lastInsertId = $conSQL->lastInsertId();

                $conSQL->commit();
                try {
                    if ($conSQL) {
                        $conSQL->beginTransaction();

                        $sqlStatment = $conSQL->prepare(

                            "INSERT INTO cliente VALUES(
                            default,
                            :idu,
                            :rfc,
                            :empresa,
                            :telefono,
                            :domicilio,
                            :contacto)");

                        $sqlStatment->bindParam(':idu', $lastInsertId);
                        $sqlStatment->bindParam(':rfc', $rfc);
                        $sqlStatment->bindParam(':empresa', $empresa);
                        $sqlStatment->bindParam(':telefono', $telefono);
                        $sqlStatment->bindParam(':domicilio', $domicilio);
                        $sqlStatment->bindParam(':contacto', $contacto);

                        //linea agregada
                        $sqlStatment->execute();



                        $conSQL->commit();
                    }

                        } catch (PDOException $e) {
                            $conSQL->rollBack();
                        }
            }

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $conSQL->rollBack();
       }
```

Agradezco de antemano su gran ayuda. :)

Comment: Hola, si no entiendo mal lo que buscas hacer, puedes solucionarlo con un trigger, que al realizar un INSERT en tu tabla USUARIO recupere el ID y lo inserte en la tabla CLIENTE.

Comment: si como dice @Lucas.D es mas facil con un trigger, lo haces que escuche el incert de la tabla usuario y ya tu le agregas los datos, y es segun lo que entendi por que no entiendo esta parte "cuando ejecuto mi código ce el segundo registro en la segunda tabla." por lo que entiendo que el segundo query no se ejecuta

Comment: Muchas gracias por el consejo. tambine lo probare. Nunca hay una sola respuesta para un problemas. Exito

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer el INSERT en ambas tablas te aconsejo que lo hagas atómico, con esto quiero decir que:

1. Abres una transacción.
2. Haces el INSERT.
3. Recuperas el id.
4. Realizas el otro INSERT.
5. Por último cierras la transacción.

En caso de que haya algún error no se guarda ningún valor, es como si nunca se hubiera hecho el INSERT, por eso usas las transacciones. El uso del **try catch** puede ser opcional, pero con este ejemplo no lo veo necesario.

Por otro lado, debe haber un [FOREIGN KEY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) como restricción en ambas tablas (cliente y usuario) y así fuerzas que haya un registro padre y evitas registranos huerfanos por código, situación que se te puede presentar si usas try catch, tambien debes definir el FOREIGN KEY como NOT NULL para mejorar el rendimiento y evitar los registros huerfanos a nivel del modelo de datos.

Por último, evita en lo posible usar TRIGGERS porque añades complejidad sin necesidad para esta situación.

Comment: Muchas gracias Nicola por el consejo, lo tratare de hacer como lo mencionas. Saludos y éxito en sus proyectos.

Answer (score 0):

Agradezco a todos los que me apoyaron con sus respuestas, pero por falta de experiencia y técnica me dispuse a hacer una tabla exclusiva para **cliente**. Hubo una ejercicio que realicé y que si pudo hacer lo que yo quería, pero no lo pude implementar en mi código. Se los comparto y aclaro que **este código no es de mi autoría completa** por si lo conocen o lo han visto en otra parte.

> Cita en bloque

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "proyecto";
try {
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (usuario, tipo, nombre, app, apm, contrasena)
 VALUES ('c11', '3', 'luis', 'felipe', 'dabila', '123')";   
 $conn->exec($sql);
 $lastInsertId = $conn->lastInsertId();
 echo 'ultimo usuario insertado ' . $lastInsertId;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
 echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
 $conn = null;
 echo '<br>';
try {
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO cliente (idu,rfc,empresa,telefono,domicilio,contacto)
 VALUES ($lastInsertId,'abc000101a2c','torito','1234567890','andador 3 #3 colonia pedrgal','mail@mail.com')";   
 $conn->exec($sql);
 $last_id2 = $conn->lastInsertId();
 echo'y el ultimo cliente fue'.$last_id2;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
}
```

Espero que les ayude si es que lo necesitan en alguna ocasión.
Suerte y éxito a todos.